# Do I need to install Bootstrap program to use templates created by Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure if you have to install Bootstrap program to use a template created by Bootstrap or not. For example if you want to use wordpress theme you have to install wordpress right? But Bootstrap is a new thing for me.

I am going to buy this template

http://themeforest.net/item/azul-creative-coming-soon-template/6642371?ref=hdalive

But if I have to install and learn how to use Bootstrap I think I'm not gonna buy it.

Comment: Bootstrap is just a set of CSS rules.

Comment: That means I don't have to install it to use Bootstrap theme right?

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap is a framework used to create responsive websites, Its not a platform and needs no installations. Since the template is built on Bootstrap, its obvious that bootstrap is included and hence You can run the theme on your server directly. To make any changes to the theme/design and customize it, you can go through the documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

If you are good at HTML and CSS it should be really easy to pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

All the necessary files will be already in place if you buy the theme.

If you want to learn and change bootstrap settings go through http://getbootstrap.com/

Bootstrap is mostly playing with defined css classes and jquery.
It is better to use custom classes to if you want to change bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I just bought the theme, and no you don't need to install Boostrap to use themes created by it. I think Bootstrap is just a tool to help created website not a platform.

Answer (score 0):

Themes come with the necessary plug-ins, so you do not need to install `bootstrap`, `jquery` etc. seperately. But if you want to add and/or modify a bootstrap component in your site, you will need to know how to use it.